# Why is this not sorting all form_id's, and how can I get it to sort

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to figure out why it's not showing form_id's in order in the results and how I can get it to show in order.  For some reason it's showing the resulting data like this:

form_id   question_id  fq_concept_id   fql_concept_id  log_date  fql_update_date  fq_update_date
50008     6            null            null             null     null             2020-08-21
50380     11           50385           null             null     null             2019-12-02
50399     8            50138           null             null     null             2020-03-05
50423     17           100             null             null     null             2020-07-02
50259     8            50084           null             null     null             2020-07-02
50265     1            50110           null             null     null             2020-08-30

```
    use cust_dev
    DECLARE @changedConcepts TABLE (form_id INT, question_id int, fq_concept_id INT, fql_concept_id int, log_date datetime, fql_update_date datetime, fq_update_date DATETIME )
--find changed concepts
insert into @changedConcepts
select FORM_QUESTION.FORM_ID,
       FORM_QUESTION.QUESTION_ID,
       FORM_QUESTION.CONCEPT_ID as fq_concept_id,
       FQL.concept_id as fql_concept_id,
       FQL.log_date,
       FQL.update_date as fql_update_date,
       FORM_QUESTION.update_date as fq_update_date
       from [ck_dev].dbo.form_question 
       --ORDER BY fql.form_id asc, form_question.form_id asc, question_id asc
  left JOIN  
(SELECT DISTINCT
       FORM_QUESTION_LOG.FORM_ID,
       FORM_QUESTION_LOG.QUESTION_ID,
       FORM_QUESTION_LOG.CONCEPT_ID,
       FORM_QUESTION_LOG.log_date,
       FORM_QUESTION_LOG.update_date --I think we need this date
 FROM [ck_dev].dbo.FORM_QUESTION_LOG-- fql
        ) FQL 
        ON FQL.FORM_ID = FORM_QUESTION.FORM_ID
        AND FQL.QUESTION_ID = FORM_QUESTION.QUESTION_ID
        AND FQL.Concept_id <> FORM_QUESTION.concept_id 
        --group by 
 ORDER BY fql.form_id asc, form_question.form_id asc, fql.question_id asc, form_question.question_id asc
```

I have a feeling it's because my form_id's are coming from separate tables, but I'm not finding in in a search (or how to fix it).  Is there a way to get them to show both the table contents in order like:

form_id   question_id  fq_concept_id   fql_concept_id  log_date  fql_update_date  fq_update_date
50008     6            null            null             null     null             2020-08-21
50259     8            50084           null             null     null             2020-07-02
50265     1            50110           null             null     null             2020-08-30
50380     11           50385           null             null     null             2019-12-02
50399     8            50138           null             null     null             2020-03-05
50423     17           100             null             null     null             2020-07-02

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ORDER BY fql.form_id asc, form_question.form_id asc, fql.question_id asc, form_question.question_id asc
```

I think you should use below order:

```
ORDER BY FORM_QUESTION.FORM_ID asc, fql.form_id asc, fql.question_id asc, form_question.question_id asc
```

Or you might consider removing fql.form_id

```
ORDER BY FORM_QUESTION.FORM_ID asc,  fql.question_id asc, form_question.question_id asc
```

fql.form_id is from the table which is used in **left join**. So there is possibility to have null in this column but table **FORM_QUESTION** will always have values (unless FORM_QUESTION.FORM_ID is nullable column).